# Cannot start apps in cloudfoundry.com

Tags: cloud-foundry

vmc start apps failed:

```
C:\Users\Vincent.Chan>vmc start TaoMoney
Starting TaoMoney... SKIPPED
Already started.
Checking TaoMoney... FAILED
```

but vmc apps and vmc delete apps works.
vmc apps get result:

```
C:\Users\Vincent.Chan>vmc apps
Getting applications... OK

name       status   usage      runtime   url
TaoMoney   0%       1 x 512M   java      taomoney.cloudfoundry.com
```

Comment: Could you check the application logs using "vmc logs" and post the output please?

Comment: C:\Users\Vincent.Chan>vmc logs TaoMoney
    Getting logs for TaoMoney #0... FAILED
    CFoundry::AppFileError: 306: Error retrieving file 'logs'
    For more information, see ~/.vmc/crash

Comment: If you supply the email address you use to log in, I can take a look at the logs myself and see what's going wrong.

Comment: ok, got it, in the interest of not getting spammed, I would remove your comment :-)

Comment: What type of Java application is it? Did it push ok using VMC?

Comment: Yes it is Java application.And I am using intellij idea 12 to do the deploy.I have deploy it successfully at the beginning,and the app work fine.And then after that day, come the fails.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the application and redeploying?

Comment: Thanks,I have just tried deleting the app and redeploying it using vmc.Now it works.